# Matching WORD pattern through regex

Tags: regex, bash, word-boundaries

Assume i have a big paragraph, in which there are words are like `found` `field` `failed` `fired` `killed` (*so many negative words i know!!*)

Now, I want to fetch line which have **words starting from** `fi` `hi` or `k` and **ends with** `eld` or `ed`

How would i go about searching this pattern of word in string....??

keep in check **that i am asking about word pattern in string, not string pattern**

These 2 surely didn't  worked

```
egrep "^(f[ai]|k)+(eld|ed)$"
```

and

```
egrep "\<(f|k)+(eld|ed)$\>"
```

I'll admit i am not a hulk of `regex`, doing it out of basic understanding, so any one willing to suggest a better way (*with some description*) is most welcome too!! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex you are probably looking for would be

```
"\b([fh]i|k)\w*(eld|ed)\b"
```

The `\w*` should be equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]*`, so that will allow any word-like characters be between requested strings.

The `\b` is there to ensure, that the word really starts and ends with letters you want. Otherwise you might for example match string which contains word `Unfailed`

Also you need to remove `$` and `^` from the regex because `$` means end of line and `^` the beginning of line.

Comment: You are welcome. Regular expressions are awesome :-]

Comment: @NoobEditor [www.regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) is a great source for learning regexes. Maybe you find an hour or two to look into it.

Comment: Basti M is right, that is an excellent source. I can only add http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html if you are fan of python. It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use

```
\<(fi|hi|k)[a-zA-Z]*?(eld|ed)\>
```

to match the words you want.

[demo @ regex101](http://regex101.com/r/oY0oU0)
(when you take a look at the demo: `\b` is the same as `\<`

Explanation:

```
\<           #beginning of word
  (fi|hi|k)  #either fi or hi or k
  [a-zA-Z]*? #zero to unlimited of a-z and A-Z
  (eld|ed)   #either eld or ed
\>           #end of word
```

If you want to allow numbers, dashes, underscores, ... within your words, simply add them to the character-class, for example: `[a-zA-Z$_]` if you want to allow `$` and `_`, too.

Comment: +1 : dint knew the regex101, quick question : when should i use `\< \>`??

Answer (score 1):

You can use word boundary `\b`.

```
^.*\b(fi|hi|k)\w*(eld|ed)\b.*$
   ------------------------
```

This pattern would select lines that contain those words

**NOTE**:You need to use multiline modifier `m` & global modifier `g`

Try it [here](http://regex101.com/r/zO1nE0)